# slider bar jquery ui change background for an image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I manage to change the background of the progresse bar for an image with an gradient, but the image moves with the handler.

Here its high, so we can see the gradien

[image]

But when it's low the image desend with, there's no gradient anymore..

[image]

how can i see the darkest part of the gradient as move up??
thanks

Comment: here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yv6Rt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the gradient to recalculate based off of position so it is obvious that it is still a gradient, then you can do this:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    background-position: inherit;
}
```

Example of a re-calculated gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/yv6Rt/365/

If you are wanting the gradient to not move at all while moving the slider, you can make it have a fixed position using this:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Example of a fixed gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/yv6Rt/366/

Comment: the thing is that the gradient moves with the handler, i need the gradient to be fixed but i can figure out how.

Comment: @novoa I updated the answer to show another option that might better fit what you are looking for. If not, I need a better explanation of what you are looking for.

Comment: Bro that's exactly what I needed, I use 'background-position:fixed;' at the beeginig, i can't belive that just with "0 100%" is working. Thank for the help man and english is not my mother tongue and I still have problems...